# What does $\mu$ and $\nu$ "dependent" mean?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

> On the other hand, if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are completely dependent then $\pi_{x_1}=\delta_{f(x_1)}$ for some function $f$. Then $W(\pi)=1$.

---

Note that
$$
\pi(dx, dy)=\pi_x(dy)\mu(dx).
$$

If $\pi_x(dy)=\delta_{f(x)}(dy)$, then

$$
\pi(dx, dy)=\pi_x(dy)\delta_{f(x)}(dy).
$$

Comment: You have two questions here. Asking multiple questions in one post is discouraged on MathOverflow.

Comment: Taking away the reference has made this question unintelligible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense to say that two probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ are "completely dependent". Dependence (or lack thereof) is a property of random elements, not of probability measures.

Also, a disintegration $(\pi_x)$ is an attribute, not of probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$, but of a coupling $\pi$ of $\mu$ and $\nu$.  On the other hand, $\mu$ and $(\pi_x)$ determine $\pi$ and hence $\nu$.

E.g., if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are each the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, then the formula $\pi_x=\nu$ for $x\in[0,1]$ determines the "independent" coupling $\pi=\mu\otimes\nu$ of $\mu$ and $\nu$, whereas the formula $\pi_x=\delta_{f(x)}$ for $f(x):=x$ and $x\in[0,1]$ determines the "completely dependent" coupling $\pi$ (of $\mu$ and $\nu$) that is the uniform distribution on the diagonal $D:=\{(x,x)\colon x\in[0,1]\}$. Functions $f$ defined by formulas $f(x):=1-x$ and $f(x):=\lfloor2x\rfloor$ for $x\in[0,1]$ provide another two examples of "completely dependent" couplings $\pi$ of $\mu$ and $\nu$, with disintegration $\pi_x=\delta_{f(x)}$.

Note also that the author of the linked paper never defines "completely dependent" probability measures, and I have never seen such nonsense elsewhere. Apparently, what the author meant by

> On the other hand, if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are completely dependent then $\pi_{x_1}=\delta_{f(x_1)}$ for some function $f$. Then $W(\pi)=1$.

is just the following:

> If the coupling $\pi$ of $\mu$ and $\nu$ is such that $\pi_{x_1}=\delta_{f(x_1)}$ for some Borel function $f$ and $\mu$-almost all $x_1\in X$, then $W(\pi)=1$.

Comment: @Hermi : (i) Apparently you meant, not the second sentence in the answer, but the third one. When I said "a disintegration $(\pi_x)$ is an attribute, not of probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$, but of a coupling $\pi$ of $\mu$ and $\nu$", I did not mean anything about the existence or uniqueness of this attribute. The point was simply that a disintegration is an attribute of $\pi$, and not of $\mu$ and $\nu$. (ii) Given $\mu$ and $(\pi_x)$, we can get $\pi$, by formula 2.16 ion p. 153 in Çinlar's book.

Comment: Previous comment continued: Given $\pi$ and assuming that the measurable space is standard, we can get the mariginals $\mu$ and $\nu$ and a disintegration $(\pi_x)$, according to Theorem 2.18 on p. 154 in Çinlar's book.

Comment: @Hermi : If you know $\pi$, then you know $\mu$. So, instead of saying "given $\pi$ and $\mu$", you can simply say "given $\pi$". Moreover, as I wrote, "Given $\pi$ and assuming that the measurable space is standard, we can get [...] a disintegration $(\pi_x)$, according to Theorem 2.18 on p. 154 in Çinlar's book."

Comment: @Hermi : For each Borel $B$, the map $x\mapsto\pi_x(B)$ will be $\mu$-almost everywhere uniquely determined. I think, if the measurable space is standard, then all the maps $x\mapsto\pi_x(B)$, for all Borel $B$ at once, will be $\mu$-almost everywhere uniquely determined. However, I do not immediately have a proof or a reference for this. You can search for such a reference yourself. All such additional questions should be asked in separate posts, possibly not on MathOverflow.